# Compatibility issue between `forest` and `etextools`

Tags: incompatibility, forest, etextools

I have the following versions of the `forest` and `etextools` packages:

```
Package: forest 2015/07/15 v1.0.10 Drawing (linguistic) trees
Package: etextools 2010/12/07 v3.1415926 e-TeX more useful tools for LaTeX pack
age writers
```

When I try to compile the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{etextools}

\begin{document}
  \begin{forest}
    [a [b] [c]] 
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
! Argument of \ettl@forloop has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.9   \end{forest}
```

The MWE works fine if I remove the `etextools` include.
How can I use both at the same time?

Comment: No, you can't. The `etextools` package redefines several constructs in `etoolbox` in incompatible ways. Unfortunately, some of the commands introduced by `etextools`, which was based on the first version of `etoolbox` were later incorporated into the “parent” package, but the “child” package didn't acknowledge it.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, I can see now that it is a problem with `etoolbox` and `etextools`. I can hack a solution to get it working by forcing the `etoolbox` macro, but I guess I will have to start using something else in the future.